# How to load JSON or see load-errors?

Tags: d3.js, loaddata

I am using a complex HTML5 page, but removed all Javascript, so it seems:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Page</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function onLOAD() {
        console.log("Hello onLoad!")
        d3.json("./myData.json", function(data) { // tested also (error, data)
          console.log("Hello data!", data);
        });
        console.log("!Bye!")
    } // \onLOAD
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="onLOAD()">    
  ... future use with myData ...
  <section><h1>... ETC..</h1>...</section>
  ...
</body>
</html>
```

No error message or "hello data" on console. Tested with Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: OK, it is a duplicate, can I delete after some answer?